# Logic app when a blob is added or modified spams me

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I set up a python code that will store a file in Blob storage. I want an email to be sent to me every time the file gets stored.  I set up a recurrence followed by [when a blob is added or modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9WE1.png).  Then when it detects the file has been added it sends me an email.  But when i upload a file to blob the logic app continuously sends emails till i disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the *Recurrence* trigger and modify the [When a blob is added or modified trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger) to check at frequency intervals (e.g. every 5 seconds). Here's what the code for your trigger could look like:

```
"When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)": {
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
        "queries": {
            "folderId": "/outagetesting",
            "maxFileCount": 1
        }
    },
    "recurrence": {
        "frequency": "Second",
        "interval": 5
    },
    "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
```

Rather than using a polling trigger, you should look into [Azure Event Grid's Blob Created Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview).